# How come my Django filter isn't working?

Tags: javascript, python, django, templates, filter

```
Submitted on {{ post.date|date:"D. M d, P" }}
Submitted {{ post.date|timesince }} ago
```

The timesince filter does not work.

```
Submitted on Tue. Jan 04, 9:45 p.m. 
Submitted 0 minutes ago
```

As you can see , the date filter works, but timesince does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `post.date` in the future?